# How can I set a default for a column with the SQLITE version used in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a SQLITE table in my Xamarin application like this:

```
public class ClickHistory
{
    [PrimaryKey, NotNull]
    public string Yymmdd { get; set; }
    public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int BtnACount { get; set; }
    public int BtnBCount { get; set; }
    public int BtnCCount { get; set; }
    public int BtnDCount { get; set; }
}

db2.CreateTable<ClickHistory>();
```

Can someone help me by telling me how I can set default values for the BtnACount, BtnBCount, BtnCCount, BtnDCount columns to a value of 0.  Right now when I do an insert but don't specify those columns it defaults to null.

Please note the suggested solution for this in another question that a person marked as a duplicate for me:

**[NotNull, Default(value: true)]**

Does not work in the version of SQLITE with Xamarin

Comment: What do you get if you use it?

Comment: which specific package name/version are you using?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If Default is supported by your SQLite, then use Default attribute

```
[Table("blabla")]
public class Blabla {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [NotNull,Default(value:1)]
    public int bleh { get; set; }
}
```

If Default is not supported by your SQLite,you can simply assign default value like this:

```
[Table("blabla")]
    public class Blabla {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [NotNull]
        public int bleh { get; set; } = 1;
    }
```

I prefer second way.